# Constructing object from file not working (constructing using data from struct works fine) (C++)

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm currently writing an ASCII game engine for the Windows console, and one of the classes I'm working with is an Image class, whose data members include width, height, and pointers to dynamically allocated arrays of unsigned chars that represent character and colour data for the image.

Originally I was constructing all of the images with data from structs defined elsewhere in the program, but that proved quite inefficient for anything past my first couple practice images so I tried to create a constructor that would read the required data from a text file instead. The format of the text file is:

width

height

[chars]

[colours]

where chars and colours are just arrays separated by whitespace of width * height size (full image file pasted below if you're interested). However, when I call this constructor, something goes wrong - in debug mode in Eclipse, nothing looks strange at all and it in fact looks like it's copying over the character and colour arrays just fine, but executing the program doesn't draw the image to the screen when it's asked to.

The original version of the constructor looks like this:

```
Image::Image(const int w, const int h, const CHAR *chrs, const COL *cols) :width(w), height(h) {
    chars = new CHAR[w * h];
    colours = new COL[w * h];
    for (int i = 0; i < w * h; ++i) {
        chars[i] = chrs[i];
        colours[i] = cols[i];
    }
}
```

and was called like so:

```
Image *sun_image = new Image(Sun.width, Sun.height, Sun.chars, Sun.colours);
```

with the Sun struct defined like this:

```
Sun_s Sun =
{
  SUNW,
  SUNH,
  {
    255,255,255,255,255,255,255,177,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,177,255,255,255,177,255,255,255,177,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255,177,255,255,255,255,255,177,255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255,255,255,177,177,177,255,255,255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255,255,177,178,219,178,177,255,255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255,177,178,219,219,219,178,177,255,255,255,255,
    177,255,177,255,177,219, 94,219, 94,219,177,255,177,255,177,
    255,255,255,255,177,178,219,126,219,178,177,255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255,255,177,178,219,178,177,255,255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255,255,255,177,177,177,255,255,255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255,177,255,255,255,255,255,177,255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,177,255,255,255,177,255,255,255,177,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255,255,255,255,177,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
  },
  {
      0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 62,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
      0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
      0,  0,  0, 62,  0,  0,  0, 62,  0,  0,  0, 62,  0,  0,  0,
      0,  0,  0,  0, 62,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 62,  0,  0,  0,  0,
      0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 62, 62, 62,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
      0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 62, 62, 14, 62, 62,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
      0,  0,  0,  0, 62, 62, 14, 14, 14, 62, 62,  0,  0,  0,  0,
     62,  0, 62,  0, 62, 14,224, 14,224, 14, 62,  0, 62,  0, 62,
      0,  0,  0,  0, 62, 62, 14,224, 14, 62, 62,  0,  0,  0,  0,
      0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 62, 62, 14, 62, 62,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
      0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 62, 62, 62,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
      0,  0,  0,  0, 62,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 62,  0,  0,  0,  0,
      0,  0,  0, 62,  0,  0,  0, 62,  0,  0,  0, 62,  0,  0,  0,
      0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
      0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 62,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
  }
};
```

The attempted new version of the constructor looks like this:

```
Image::Image(const char *filename) {
    std::ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(filename, std::ios::in);

    if (inputFile.is_open()) {
        inputFile >> width;
        inputFile >> height;
        chars = new CHAR[width * height];
        colours = new CHAR[width * height];

    int temp, i;
    for (i = 0; i < height * width; ++i) {
        inputFile >> temp;
        chars[i] = (CHAR)temp;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < width * height; ++i) {
        inputFile >> temp;
        colours[i] = (CHAR)temp;
    }
    } else {
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
        chars = new CHAR[width * height];
        colours = new CHAR[width * height];
    }

inputFile.close();
}
```

with a call that looks like:

```
    Image *sun_image = new Image("./artassets/sun.txt");
```

and a sun.txt that looks like:

```
15
15

255 255 255 255 255 255 255 177 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 
255 255 255 177 255 255 255 177 255 255 255 177 255 255 255 
255 255 255 255 177 255 255 255 255 255 177 255 255 255 255 
255 255 255 255 255 255 177 177 177 255 255 255 255 255 255 
255 255 255 255 255 177 178 219 178 177 255 255 255 255 255 
255 255 255 255 177 178 219 219 219 178 177 255 255 255 255 
177 255 177 255 177 219  94 219  94 219 177 255 177 255 177 
255 255 255 255 177 178 219 126 219 178 177 255 255 255 255 
255 255 255 255 255 177 178 219 178 177 255 255 255 255 255 
255 255 255 255 255 255 177 177 177 255 255 255 255 255 255 
255 255 255 255 177 255 255 255 255 255 177 255 255 255 255 
255 255 255 177 255 255 255 177 255 255 255 177 255 255 255 
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 177 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  62   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0  62   0   0   0  62   0   0   0  62   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0  62   0   0   0   0   0  62   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0   0  62  62  62   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0  62  62  14  62  62   0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0  62  62  14  14  14  62  62   0   0   0   0 
 62   0  62   0  62  14 224  14 224  14  62   0  62   0  62 
  0   0   0   0  62  62  14 224  14  62  62   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0  62  62  14  62  62   0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0   0  62  62  62   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0  62   0   0   0   0   0  62   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0  62   0   0   0  62   0   0   0  62   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  62   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? My two constructors don't look all that different to me...

EDIT: Forgot to mention, CHAR and COL are both just defines for unsigned char.

Comment: Please don't use `new`. Use `std::vector` in the class and a normal object when you make an object.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what it is that doesn't work?

Comment: I have another function called write_image_to_buffer which does exactly as the name implies - except when it's called on an image constructed using the filename constructor, it doesn't seem to do anything. It works perfectly as expected everywhere else - only failing on images I try to construct this way.

Comment: I take it you have checked (by adding some output in the relevant paths) that your file opens correctly?

Comment: The else block won't work because you are trying to create arrays of size zero.

Comment: @Vincent: I'm pretty sure that's UB, so I wouldn't RELY on it "not working" - at least not rely on it "not working in a way that is obvious enough that we can conclude that the file wasn't opened".

Comment: @MatsPetersson: you're right, by 'not working' I didn't mean it won't work at runtime. But I don't see the point of doing this instead of just setting the pointer to null which is a defined behaviour.

Comment: I checked that the file opens correctly using Eclipse debug, stepping through the function itself and making sure that it steps into the if loop at that point instead of the else loop... Also changed the else block around a bit, thank you for pointing that out, so it now initializes chars and colours to null instead of allocating space for them. Still having the same issue but at least I won't run into that problem later ^^